# Renaming of the tag [netherlands] to [the-netherlands]

Tags: feature-request

Coming across the tag being called "Netherlands" thew me, as I always refer to that country as "The Netherlands". Asking a few dutch friends (perhaps half a dozen or so) they all agreed that their country should be referred to as "The Netherlands" rather than just "Netherlands" in English. This is just a request for [netherlands](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/netherlands) to be renamed to [the-netherlands](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-netherlands)

This may have arisen as in Dutch the "The" is dropped and is just called "Netherlands" ("Nederland"), however in English it is referred to as "The Netherlands".

Of course if a significant number of Dutch members on this SE all disagree with my findings, then it would only be fair to keep it as it is as 1. It's your country, and hence your opinion takes priority over those of non-Dutch people, and 2. Seeing as you are the main ones using this SE it's only fair we listen to you rather than people who do not.

It's worth noting another SE currently does this - [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/netherlands) and [Academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/netherlands)- however while surfing their meta there appears to have been no discussion on what to call it, and no reasoning as to why it is called [netherlands](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/netherlands) rather than [the-netherlands](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-netherlands). It's also worth noting in the tag description they both refer to the country as "The Netherlands".

Comment: One solution would be to make the-netherlands a synonym with netherlands.

Comment: Are there other SE sites with country specific tags? What do they do for this case?

Comment: I found another site that does - I'll cover it and edit the question now.

Comment: Maybe it's similar to "the United States" being tagged "united-states"? I don't know if there's a rule (grammatical or otherwise) about it, but glancing at the Travel.SE tags it looks like countries starting with "the" don't have it included in the tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's good enough for [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netherlands), it's good enough for us.

While France and Germany and England don't require "the", many countries do... the Netherlands, the United States, the United Kingdom... but the "the" isn't part of the name of the country, it's an artifact of the name being collective.

It's [worth noting](http://www.bbc.com/news/magazine-18233844):

> There are many other country names that are habitually referred to with "the", such as Congo, Gambia, Yemen, Lebanon, Sudan, Netherlands, Philippines and Bahamas.
>
> But according to several authoritative sources, such as the CIA World Factbook, the Times Comprehensive Atlas of the World and the US Department of State, only two countries, The Bahamas and The Gambia, should officially be referred to with the article.
>
> The two Congos are officially Democratic Republic of the Congo and Republic of the Congo. And the longer, official name for Netherlands is Kingdom of the Netherlands.

There's a bunch of additional information in this very informative article but... in the end, we're already shortening "Kingdom of the Netherlands", I don't really see why we should keep the "the".

Comment: Having done some more research into the name "Netherlands" itself I can understand why some countries have the "the" before them now - thanks for helping clear this up!

Comment: The Kingdom of Spain is known as Spain. By similarity, why not shorten "The Kingdom of the Netherlands" to "the Netherlands"? In both cases, you drop "The Kingdom of" and keep "what it is a kingdom of".

Comment: Also, if you read past the Wikipedia title (which cannot be edited as far as I could see) you will see that the country is referred to as "The Netherlands" throughout (including the first two words of the article).

Answer (score 4):

While I agree about "the" prefixed for "Netherlands" in general, I don't think it's necessary to rename tags to "the-netherlands". I'd go for shorter tags, just like it's "united-states" instead of "united-states-of-america".

Other SE sites use "netherlands" without the *the* for tags.

https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/netherlands
https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/netherlands
https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/netherlands
https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/netherlands
https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/netherlands
https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/netherlands
https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/netherlands

Comment: And, technically, it would be "the United States"... you can't say "I went to United States" any more than you can say "I went to Netherlands". Even Wikipedia is just "[Netherlands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netherlands)"...

Comment: @Catija Correct. It's also "the United Arab Emirates" in that sense, the country I live in. Although, for the sake of convenience, a lot of flight services and news papers avoid the _the_ entirely.

Comment: Aligning with other SE sites makes the most sense

Comment: I like this answer. Instead of claiming that "Netherlands" is OK as the name for the country (I argue, as a citizen of the Kingdom of the Netherlands, that it is not OK), it says "let's use a shorthand", and let's stay consistent with other SE sites.